# Assist writing awk script version of python code to generate count matrix

Tags: python, matrix, awk, count, sequence

I have not found any similar question to this...

I have this python script to generate a count matrix from files containing only sequences, but it takes eternity to run but I know awk will do a faster job. i am not so good with awk but hoping someone might be able to help.
the python script is as follows:

```
    numFiles = int(sys.argv[1])
    allParams = int(numFiles + 4)
    key_file = sys.argv[2]
    out_file = sys.argv[3]
    #open the output file
    outHandle = open(out_file,'w')
    #Open key file and read one line at a time
    with open(key_file) as kf:
            for eachline in kf:
                    temp_list = [0] * numFiles
                    kSeq = eachline.strip(' \t\n\r')
                    upRange = int(numFiles + 4)

                    for i in range(4,upRange):
                            with open(sys.argv[i]) as f:
                                    for eachline in f:
                                            seq = eachline.strip(' \t\n\r')
                                            if (kSeq == seq):
                                                    curr = int(temp_list[i-4])
                                                    nw = int(curr + 1)
                                                    temp_list[i-4] = nw
                                            else:
                                                    continue

                    outHandle.write(str(kSeq) + "\t")
                    for ind,item in enumerate(temp_list):
                            lastItemIndex = numFiles - 1
                            if(ind == lastItemIndex):
                                    outHandle.write(str(item) + "\n")
                            else:
                                    outHandle.write(str(item) + "\t")
```

Trying to create an example:

Input: A keyFile, X number of other files (All input file are basically just words in a single column)
Output: A matrix containing the number of occurrence of the words in the keyFile in the X number of files.

Keyfile:

| word |
| --- |
| one |
| two |
| three |
| four |
| five |

file1:

| word |
| --- |
| three |
| five |
| three |
| one |
| two |
| one |
| four |
| four |
| three |

file2:

| word |
| --- |
| four |
| one |
| three |
| three |
| one |
| two |
| three |
| two |
| one |

OUTPUT:

| word | file1 | file2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 2 | 3 |
| two | 1 | 2 |
| three | 3 | 3 |
| four | 2 | 1 |
| five | 1 | 0 |

the number of files could be up to 4

I hope this illustration is clearer.

Thank you

Comment: You're assuming that a) someone who's an expert in awk will also understand the details of python and b) the way that python script is written is the best way to do whatever you're trying to do in python. If you'd like help writing an awk script then post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus a statement of your requirements and tell us where you're running into a problem doing that so we can help you with it. See [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for the guided response. I will modify this as suggested

Comment: *takes eternity to run but I know awk will do a faster job* before throwing away your already working solution I suggest profiling to detect what is consuming most of time and examing if improving that is possible.

Comment: @Daweo: I know based on my experience running scripts using python and doing the same with awk, especially when a one-against-all comparison is made in files. AWK is just faster than python in such cases.

Comment: @user2960998 ```AWK is just faster than python in such cases.```. Depends on how good you're with awk vs how bad you're with python. Or vice versa. It'd ambiguous hard to generalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after extensive reading and tries, i got what I wanted to achieve using the code

`awk 'fname != FILENAME { fname = FILENAME; idx++ } idx == 1 {key[$0] = $0 } idx == 2 {if($1 == key[$1]){ f1[$1] += 1 }} idx == 3 {if($1 == key[$1]){ f2[$1] += 1 }} END {for(seq in key) print seq "\t" f1[seq] "\t" f2[seq] }' keyFile file1 file2`

Thanks all for your input.